# Determine if Mac laptop is using battery power or wall charger

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, macbook-pro

In the top right of the menu bar it says "not charging" -- but I also have a suspicion that it is not using battery power either.

Is there any way to tell if a Mac is using battery power besides the icon in the menu bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a little trick I found.  If you go to System Preferences -> Energy Saver.

If you unplug the charger you will notice (if it is somewhat working) that the "Battery" tab becomes highlighted, and when you plug the charger back in -- the "Power Adapter" tab will highlighted.  If the tabs don't change, i think it is safe to say that it is not recognizing the charger at all, and you aren't getting any juice.